# Create and destroy Angular watchers

Tags: angularjs

I would like to turn off this watcher because it keeps hitting "kendoWidgetCreated" event over and over again, and causes an infinite loop where I hit the `kendoGrid.refresh()` .

How can I turn it off, then turn back on ?

```js
scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function (ev, widget) {

  var kendoGrid = widget.element.parent().find('.k-grid').data("kendoGrid");
  if (kendoGrid != undefined) {
      kendoGrid.$angular_scope.compileTemplate();
      kendoGrid.refresh();
  }

});
```

I tried something like this, but couldn't get the watcher to trigger :

```
  var kendoWidgetWatcher = scope.$watch("kendoWidgetCreated", refreshKendoWidgets);

  var refreshKendoWidgets = function (ev, widget) {

           // widget compile/refresh code here...
  }
```

Advice is always appreciated...

regards,
Bob

***** UPDATE ****
My initial idea for creating an anonymous function was NOT working; however, Pankar's answer below worked for me. 
Here's the updated, working version :

```js
// setup new 'kendoWidgetWatcher' object for Kendo widget watcher, compile/refresh Kendo grids/charts
var kendoWidgetWatcher;
function registerWatcher() {
  kendoWidgetWatcher = scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", refreshKendoWidgets);
}              

function refreshKendoWidgets(ev, widget) {

  var ht = widget.getSize().height;
  var wt = widget.getSize().width;
  
  var kendoGrid = widget.element.parent().find('.k-grid').data("kendoGrid");
  if (kendoGrid != undefined) {
      if (kendoWidgetWatcher) {
   kendoWidgetWatcher();     // disable watch
      }
      kendoGrid.$angular_scope.compileTemplate();  // recompile the html tempate, then refresh kendo widget
      kendoGrid.refresh();
      registerWatcher();    //  re-enable
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily turn off your your watcher by calling the watcher reference as function, and re-register it whenever you want it.

```
var kendoWidgetWatcher;
```

```js
function refreshKendoWidgets(ev, widget) {
 
  var kendoGrid = widget.element.parent().find('.k-grid').data("kendoGrid");
  if (kendoGrid != undefined) {
    kendoGrid.$angular_scope.compileTemplate();
    kendoGrid.refresh();        
    // HOW TO DISABLE THE WATCH HERE ?
  }
}
```

```
function registerWatcher (){
    kendoWidgetWatcher = scope.$watch("kendoWidgetCreated", refreshKendoWidgets);
}
registerWatcher();

//you could call below code for re-registering the watcher
if(kendoWidgetWatcher)
  kendoWidgetWatcher(); //to deregister it.
registerWatcher(); //re-register it.
```

Comment: thanks for that. I actually tried this but the watcher doesn't trigger. I'm setting a debug point in Chrome tools but it's as if the watch is NOT registered. Something in my syntax ?

Comment: I added the function `refreshKendoWidgets` but how to disable the watcher ?

Comment: You need to call `if(kendoWidgetWatcher)
  kendoWidgetWatcher();` inside the `// HOW TO DISABLE THE WATCH HERE ?` comment

Comment: please see your answer, which I updated accordingly. I need to turn it back on kendoGrid.refresh();